# ESLint misunderstanding Flow class property type definition

Tags: javascript, eslint, flowtype

I'm using ESLint with Flow, and have some trouble in class syntax. Here's the code:

```
interface ITransactionState {
  activeKey: string;
  panes: Object;
  selectedRow: Array<any>;
  loading: boolean;
  data: Array<any>;
}

interface ITransactionProps {}

export default class Transaction extends Component<ITransactionProps, ITransactionState> {
  // Type Defs
  newTabIndex: number;              // ESLint said: newTabIndex should be placed after onEdit
  state: ITransactionState;         // ESLint said: state shouod be placed after constructor

  constructor(props:ITransactionProps) {
      ...
  }
  ...
```

In constructor, there are two variables: newTabIndex, and state. However ESLint keep shows me error that those variables must be located under blabla.

Is there a way to ESLint understand the type definition in Flow/TypeScript, or just ignore that line without manually ignoring each line?

Comment: Doesn't anyone know how to solve this? I'm stuck in here, using eslint-plugin-flowtype won't worked either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding this rules:

```
'react/sort-comp': [1, {
  order: [
    'type-annotations',    // THIS FIXED MY ERROR
    'static-methods',
    'lifecycle',
    'everything-else',
    'render'
  ]
}],
```

Hope this helps!